# Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at .pl

Tags: perl

```
if (defined($line) && $line =~ /✓  /) {
    # print "using test id****************** $current_test_id";
    my %test = %{$tests[$current_test_id]};
    $test{'passed'}++;
    $test_collection_info{'successful_tests'}++;
    $tests[$current_test_id] = \%test;

    if ($line =~ /v\ \[WARNING\]/) {
            $test_collection_info{'unstable_tests'}++;
    }
} 
elsif (defined($line) && $line =~ /✗|AssertionFailure/) {
    if (!defined($tests[$current_test_id])) {
        $test_collection_info{'failed_tests'}++;
    }
    else {
        my %test = %{$tests[$current_test_id]};
        $test{'failed'}++;
        $test_collection_info{'failed_tests'}++;
        push(@{$test{'errors'}}, \$line);
        $tests[$current_test_id] = \%test;
    }
}
```

This is the line with suspecting error:

```
my %test = %{$tests[$current_test_id]};
```

**Error: **

> Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at .pl line 105.

Can someone help if anything wrong in this script?

Comment: Are you sure `$current_test_id` is a valid array index?

Comment: If "_line 105_" is indeed the one you point out, the error is telling you that `$tests[$current_test_id]` is undefined, plain and simple. But where this is defined (or, rather, not) is not shown in your code, it happens earlier.  Thus I don't see how to guess it.

Comment: In the `@tests` you have undefined value for the given `$current_test_id` index. Therefore, the `my %test = %{$tests[$current_test_id]};` looks like `my %tests = %{undef}` - and compains about _cant use undef as hashref_. See the @ysth's asnwer. Btw, exists many modules for dumping data structures, like `Data::Dumper`, `Data::Dump`, `DDP`, `XXX` etc....

Comment: `my %test = %{$tests[$current_test_id]};` => `my $test = $tests[$current_test_id] ||= {};` and later `$test->{'passed'}++;` (wipe out `$tests[$current_test_id] = \%test;`)

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like this code:

```
                    my %test = %{$tests[$current_test_id]};
                    $test{'passed'}++;
                    $test_collection_info{'successful_tests'}++;
                    $tests[$current_test_id] = \%test;
```

can be simplified to:

```
                    $test_collection_info{'successful_tests'}++;
                    $tests[$current_test_id]{'passed'}++;
```

and work even the first time a given test passes.